# Tensorflow C++ error when using CV Mat image

Tags: c++, opencv, tensorflow

I am trying to create a custom OCR engine using Tensorflow(v1.10) in Ubuntu 18.04, with Bazel (0.16) in C++.

### Issues Faced

- Core Dumped Error for dtype mismatch (0 vs 1)
- Predicted value of weights is higher than 1, when Tensorflow Session is re-run in loop

  std::vector outputs;

  ```
  for (size_t i=0; i<filenames.size(); i++)
  {
      cv::Mat image = cv::imread(filenames[i]);

      Tensor image_tensor (tensorflow::DT_FLOAT, tensorflow::TensorShape{1,tf_height,tf_width,3});
      image.convertTo(image, CV_32FC1);
      tensorflow::StringPiece tmp_data = image_tensor.tensor_data();
      memcpy(const_cast<char*>(tmp_data.data()), (image.data), tf_height * tf_width * sizeof(float));

      // Creating a Session with the Graph
      std::unique_ptr<tensorflow::Session> session(tensorflow::NewSession(tensorflow::SessionOptions()));
      //session->tensorflow::reset(tensorflow::NewSession(tensorflow::SessionOptions()));
      tensorflow::Status session_create_status = session->Create(graph_def);

      std::vector<std::pair<string, tensorflow::Tensor>> inputs = {{inputLayer, image_tensor}};
      outputs.clear();
      Status runStatus = session->Run(inputs, {outputLayer}, {}, &outputs);
      if (!runStatus.ok()) {
          LOG(ERROR) << "Running model failed: " << runStatus;
          return -1;
      }
      cv::imshow("Original Image",image);
      cv::waitKey();
      session->Close();
      image.release();
  }"Original Image",image);
      cv::waitKey();
      session->Close();
      image.release();
  }
  ```

Comment: Check whether you have read the image in.

Comment: @Silencer. I am sure I have. The imshow displays the image